# "✔ Detected project type: hardhat ✖ Compilation failed SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

Tags: solidity, hardhat

**smart contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract CrowdFunding {
    struct Campaign {
        address owner;
        string title;
        string description;
        uint256 target;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountCollected;
        string image;
        address[] donators;
        uint256[] donations;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Campaign) public campaigns;

    uint256 public numberOfCampaigns = 0;

    function createCampaign(address _owner, string memory _title, string memory _description, uint256 _target, uint256 _deadline, string memory _image) public returns (uint256) {
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[numberOfCampaigns];

        require(campaign.deadline < block.timestamp, "The deadline should be a date in the future.");

        campaign.owner = _owner;
        campaign.title = _title;
        campaign.description = _description;
        campaign.target = _target;
        campaign.deadline = _deadline;
        campaign.amountCollected = 0;
        campaign.image = _image;

        numberOfCampaigns++;

        return numberOfCampaigns - 1;
    }

    function donateToCampaign(uint256 _id) public payable {
        uint256 amount = msg.value;

        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];

        campaign.donators.push(msg.sender);
        campaign.donations.push(amount);

        (bool sent,) = payable(campaign.owner).call{value: amount}("");

        if(sent) {
            campaign.amountCollected = campaign.amountCollected + amount;
        }
    }

    function getDonators(uint256 _id) view public returns (address[] memory, uint256[] memory) {
        return (campaigns[_id].donators, campaigns[_id].donations);
    }

    function getCampaigns() public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        Campaign[] memory allCampaigns = new Campaign[](numberOfCampaigns);

        for(uint i = 0; i < numberOfCampaigns; i++) {
            Campaign storage item = campaigns[i];

            allCampaigns[i] = item;
        }

        return allCampaigns;
    }
}
```

here is hardhat code

```
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: '0.8.9',
    defaultNetwork: 'goerli',
    networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      goerli: {
        url: 'https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_goerli',
        accounts: [`0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`]
      }
    },
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
};
```